# how to solve internal hinge problem with loading given on hinge

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structures, statics, beam

how to solve internal hinge problem with loading given on hinge
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Did you know that you can solve this by area-moment method? or conjugate-beam method? or double integration method?

Answer (score 1):

A hinge just means that the moment in the beam at that point is 0. Each beam cantilevers from the pin support to the hinge point, but we know that the deflection of each cantilever must be the same at the hinge point.

In the particular example you have shown, you can therefore use symmetry to split the structure into two at the hinge point, with 10kN in each direction.

Comment: can u explain what will happen for non symmetry problem

Comment: @deb, you better use conjugate beam methods. :)

Comment: ok thank u but my question is how to use conjugate beam method ,i use this method to solve slope and deflection type problem

Answer (score 1):

Here is the conjugate beam method to start off your analysis.

[image: Conjugate beam method]

We have 3 unknowns. $M, R, and\ V$.

Summing up moment at the conjugate internal hinge (going towards the free end) gives the first equation.

Summing up moment at the conjugate pin/hinge support (going towards the free end) gives the second equation.

Summing up forces along y-axis gives a reaction at the conjugate hinge.

Lastly, using the reaction from the conjugate hinge and summing up moment at the free end (involves the whole figure) gives the third equation.

Three equations, three unknowns, gives the answer.

Note: If the system is non-symmetric, the number of unknowns becomes 6. Therefore, you need to do the summing up of moments to the other side of the beam to get *another three* equation. :)

Here is the figure that is described in the other answer:

[image]